# Is it possible to have flash access a generic TWAIN Scanner?

Tags: java, flash, twain, image-scanner

Is it possible to have flash access a generic twain scanner from my web-application, save the file and upload it into my application?

I have done some searching through google but wasn't able to find to much detail in this.
Is there any pre-made solutions, Paid / Free (ideally).

If Flash isn't the best route to go, would Java Applet be better, if so, is their a solution already built?

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is an answer your looking for or not, or if this is really even an answer, or more of a comment.  It's possible, but you'd have to do it in Adobe Air 2 as you'd need to take advantage of Air's out of browser elevated permissions.  You could also do the same with Silverlight 4's elevated out of browser permissions as well.

If you want to stay in the browser at the moment you're stuck with activex, or a java applet.  Lots of people have a activex twain, or java applet twain  solutions -- just do a search for them to find them.  There are also some twain browser plugins as well, but I haven't had the chance to work with them yet.

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=activex+twain

or

http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=twain+java+applet

or

http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=twain+browser+extension