# image scanning in a c# program running on Windows XP

Tags: c#, wia, scanning, twain

Is there a direct windows based library that I can use to scan a document in c#?
Or my only option is to use a commercial vendor such as leadtools, dynamsoft etc.
I tried to use the wiaaut.dll and it is not compatible with older windows versions such a s XP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977226/document-scanning-from-asp-net-web-application

Comment: thanks for the link. I keep getting error about missing dll - ltkrn15u.dll. Understand the dll is from leadtools, but i am evaluating dynamsoft.

Comment: http://www.dynamsoft.com/Downloads/WebTWAIN-Sample-Download.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Windows XP included any TWAIN or scanning support built into the OS. TWAIN drivers were always supplied by the scanner vendor.  So if you're wanting a no-third-party-libs solution that runs on Windows XP, I think you're out of luck.