# Is there a way to upload a pdf directly from a scanner instead of saving it on a disk first?

Tags: php, html, pdf, file-upload

Using `<input type="file">` allows someone to upload a pdf already on their system.

What if they are about to scan a massive document that they do not want taking up space on disk? Is there a way to upload a file directly from a scanner?

Comment: not unless the scanner software (printer driver) has a function to stream the data to a url instead of a file

Comment: HTML forms offer basic upload functionality, it cannot be integrated with the scanner's TWAIN. You can try alternative solutions demonstrated in this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5303743/156811

Comment: To do it through the browser would obviously require a custom ActiveX plugin in the browser or some nonsense like that. Bad idea. Better to find a scanner with the capability to upload to cloud storage without even connecting to a PC.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the button on the front of the device?
There are a number of methods.
On windows, almost every device has an api you can access  http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5440657
On Linux, everything is done on the command line anyways, a script for the basic execution commands is a snap. http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-scan-image-commands/
Really it all depends on what device and what operating system you are using.